# Lost the second of the datetime when exporting to the CSV file?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

It will lost the second when exporting to the csv file?
why?
"%S" is none?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2011-01-01 10:15:20', '2016-11-17 08:22:10'],
'text': ['red', 'purple'],'datetime': ['2011-01-01 10:15:20', '2016-11-17 08:22:10']})
df.to_csv("test.csv",date_format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

In the csv file ,it is:

```
    date    text    datetime
0   2011/1/1 10:15  red 2011/1/1 10:15
1   2016/11/17 8:22 purple  2016/11/17 8:22
```

Comment: How are you opening the CSV? The program used might be doing some formatting. Your code works for me

Comment: "%S"  does not display the second?

Comment: I ran `cat test.csv` after your code and the seconds were displayed, whatever program you are opening the file with is doing some funky formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the file in the Excel Application, the seconds would be truncated based on the default format. I would recommend to open the file in text editors like - Notepad++, Sublime where the format is preserved.

I ran the below code as it is,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2011-01-01 10:15:20', '2016-11-17 08:22:10'],
'text': ['red', 'purple'],'datetime': ['2011-01-01 10:15:20', '2016-11-17 08:22:10']})
df.to_csv("test.csv",date_format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Below is the output I got when opened in Notepad++

[image]

Comment: Sorry!   It is ok.  it display the above ,just because opening with EXCEL

Comment: Sorry!   It is ok.  it display the above ,just because opening with EXCEL